# three.js issues: application suddenly wont work on Chrome - old code, wont work with new three.js library

Tags: javascript, three.js, webgl

I wrote a few three.js (R48) applications a while back, and they've been working fine for up until a few weeks when I found they no longer work on Chrome.

Here are the first few error messages:

```
WebGL: INVALID_OPERATION: getAttribLocation: program not linked skyWheel.html:1
8
WebGL: INVALID_OPERATION: getUniformLocation: program not linked skyWheel.html:1
Could not initialise shader
VALIDATE_STATUS: false, gl error [1282] Three.js:355
29
WebGL: INVALID_OPERATION: getUniformLocation: program not linked
```

It still works fine with Firefox.

So I downloaded the latest version of three.js, and when I use it instead of the old version, I get this message and it doesn't work.  (this is on Firefox)

```
[21:50:32.679] TypeError: material is undefined @ file:Three.js:23513
```

I was just hoping someone went though this type of thing recently and can save me some time fixing these problems.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try to use minified version or developer version **(three.min.js)**.. because using them in the examples works fine even if they use backdated version :)
if not,
 i used canvas renderer and omitted the spotlight and shut down shadow mapping for renderer
and yes it is caused by **THREE.WebglRenderer()**. use  **THREE.CanvasRenderer()**. though it wont provide you the ***desired*** output.. :(

Answer (score 3):

Many things hace changed since r48. Have a look at the [migration page](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/wiki/Migration).